# Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'node_modules\dotenv\lib' - Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to use dotenv in React for API_URL. When I use it in index.js page in Next.js. I get this error

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'node_modules\dotenv\lib'

Import trace for requested module:
./pages/index.js
```

I am using dotenv by these methods:

1.

```
import { config } from 'dotenv';
config();
```

2. 

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
```

3. 

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

My package.json file is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.1",
    "next": "12.0.10",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `dotenv` with Next.js. [Here is guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) how to use environment variables in Next.js.